# Firestore Promises Query Collection in For Loop (Nuxt.js)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I've essentially been trying to simulate a join statement in Firestore joining a user to a comment by iterating over the collection of comments. I understand that when you query a collection, it returns a promise and the response, however, I'm not sure how to iterate over the documents in the response and perform another query within the for loop.

Here is a basic example

```
asyncData ({ params }) {
  var postRef = Firestore.collection('posts').doc(params.post);
  var commentRef = 
    Firestore.collection('posts').doc(params.post).collection('comments');
    return commentRef.orderBy('created_on', 'desc').get().then(snapshot => {
        var comments = []
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            var docData = doc.data()
            comments.push({
                comment: { data: doc.data(), id: doc.id }
            })
        })
        return comments
    })
    .then(data => {
        var comments = []
        for(const comment of data) {
            Firestore.collection('users-public').doc(comment.comment.data.created_by).get()
            .then(doc => {
                console.log('Got the User!')
                comments.push( {
                    comment: { data: comment.comment.data, id: comment.comment.id },
                    user: doc.data()
                })
            })
        }
        console.log("Returning!")
        return {comments: comments}
    })
},
```

When this runs, it console logs "Returning!" before "Got the User!" because they are asynchronous calls. I tried using for...of but that doesn't work. Any way to prevent this and wait for all the async calls to finish before returning? Its critical that I can resolve the promise calls to the User collection and call .data() otherwise I get a circular to json error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try storing all the promises on an array, and then calling the [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method on it. This is like a wrapper for a set of promises, that executes the callback as soon as all promises are executed.

If you like this approach, your code would look something like this:

```
asyncData({ params }) {
    var postRef = Firestore.collection('posts').doc(params.post);
    var commentRef =
        Firestore.collection('posts').doc(params.post).collection('comments');
    return commentRef.orderBy('created_on', 'desc').get().then(snapshot => {
        var comments = []
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            var docData = doc.data()
            comments.push({
                comment: { data: doc.data(), id: doc.id }
            })
        })
        return comments
    })
        .then(data => {
            var comments = []
            // Declare an empty array, where we'll store all the promises
            var promises = []
            for (const comment of data) {
                let promise = Firestore.collection('users-public').doc(comment.comment.data.created_by).get()
                // Push the promise to the array
                promises.push(promise)
            }
            // Callback on this method will execute once all promises on array have been resolved
            Promise.all(promises).then(users => {
                console.log("All users fetched!")
                // users is an array with every promise result for every user query
                users.forEach(user => {
                    let userId = result.id
                    // Attach user to every comment owned by him
                    comments.filter(comment => {
                        return comment.comment.data.created_by === userId
                    }).map(comment => {
                        comment.user = user.data()
                    })
                })
                console.log("Returning!")
                return { comments: comments }
            })
        })
}
```

As an alternative, you can use a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to handle flow from asynchronous functions.

Hope this helps!